# Das Tempus und Verkürzungen im Aufsatz

Tags: style, past, tense

Wenn man einen Aufsatz schreibt, soll man eher das Perfekt oder das Imperfekt verwenden? Oder ist es vielleicht egal?

Darf man darüber hinaus darin Verkürzungen wie *im* statt *in dem* schreiben?

Gilt dasselbe, wenn man einen formellen Brief schreibt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es kommt natürlich sehr auf die Art deines Aufsatzes oder deines Briefes an. Und es hängt auch davon ab, in welchem Rahmen du ihn schreibst.

Grundsätzlich gilt allerdings, dass in Aufsätzen das Präteritum bevorzugt werden sollte. Selbst Bayern wie ich, die in gesprochener Sprache nur *wollt(e)* und *war* als Präteritumsformen kennen, haben unsere Schulaufsätze ausschließlich in der für uns ungewohnten Zeitform verfasst.

Bei den Verkürzungen aus Präposition und Artikel ist die Sache ein bisschen vertrakter. Es hängt auch davon ab, wie etabliert das Wort, das beim Verkürzen entsteht, ist. Beispielsweise würde ich *im* und *am* schreiben, *aufs* nur vielleicht, *ins* wahrscheinlich nicht, *aufm* mit Sicherheit nicht.

Vermutlich könnte man daraus eine Regel destillieren, dass nur Verkürzungen, die mit *dem* gebildet werden, wobei ein *n* der Präposition zu *m* wird, erlaubt sind; aber das erscheint mir arg künstlich. Da würde ich lieber im Einzelfall entscheiden wollen. Nimm zwischenzeitlich mit, dass *im* und *am* gehen, und schreibe den Rest im Zweifel aus.

Ein formeller Brief ist zwar vom Prinzip etwas anderes als ein Aufsatz, ich würde aber im Zweifel die gleichen Grundsätze ansetzen. Wobei mir in meinen Briefen (die Gott sei Dank bisher höchstens mittelförmlich waren) gerne mal ein Perfekt »herausrutscht«.

Comment: Und darf man dann solche Konstruktion nutzen: `Die Briefe muss ich übersehen haben.`? Ich finde keine andere Weise, es ohne das Infinitiv Perfekt zu äußern.

Comment: @marmistrz wenn, dann ohne über: »[…] muss ich übersehen haben.« Die Konstruktion würde ich auch nicht als klassisches Perfekt einordnen, eben weil das konjugierte Verb (*müssen*) im Präsens steht. Grundsätzlich sollten alle Infinitivperfekte in Ordnung sein; die Ausnahmen sage ich dir, wenn sie mir einfallen (Wörter, die *per se* nicht in Ordnung sind (»Das muss ich verschissen haben«) selbstverfreilich ausgeschlossen ;)).

Comment: Noch eine Frage: Die Zeitenfolge sagt, dass Präsens nur mit Perfekt stehen kann. Darf es dann so ein Satz im Aufsatz geschrieben werden? *Nur ist das Ausmaß dieses Wandels viel kleiner, weil Polen für Jahrzehnten vom Westeuropa isoliert worden ist.*

Comment: @marmistrz Das ist Perfekt Passiv; das stößt mir gleich als unschön auf. Besser: »Weil Polen isoliert war« oder »weil Polen isoliert wurde«. *War* halte ich für besser, obwohl man durchaus Argumente finden kann, dass auch die passivische Form gestattet ist (Polen hat sich schließlich seine Isolation nicht ausgesucht). Aber solche Fragen kannst du auch im [chat] stellen ;)